# How to create a foreground service in NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript, android-gps, nativescript-angular

A background service might not be working in real-time if the App turned background when Android SDK > 26 (Android OS 8.0 later), but a foreground service may work according to Ref1 & Ref2(Codes in Native Java), I'm no idea how translate it in NativeScript, could somebody make it? thanks!

- Ref1: https://hackernoon.com/android-location-tracking-with-a-service-80940218f561
- Ref2: https://bitbucket.org/tiitha/backgroundserviceexample/branches/

Answer (score 0):

A foreground service example in NativeScript could be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6994) and [downloaded](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/files/2940493/ns-test-android.zip) for reference.